# Service is being stop when phone sleep

Tags: android, android-service, java-threads

I created a (AutoTestService)service to perform some task's in a single cycle manner. After finishing the cycle, setting alarm for next cycle to perform task's (Alarm call again AutoTestService). In Each task I am pausing thread for 10/20 (Using Thread.sleep)seconds and going to next task.Service Iam starting for WakefulBroadcastReceiver using AlarmManaager.

Its working fine when phone screen is on and if connected to USB. But if phone sleep without USB my service is stop execution.I am suspecting thread.sleep not resume when phone is in sleep. App running in android 5.1 & 5.1.1

Can any one give suggestion is appreciated. I am struggling this from long.

Comment: Did you try with [`Service#startForeground()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29). Works fine for me.

Comment: I didn't this . Where to use this startForeground

Comment: In the Service. Do some research by yourself. Read the documentation I linked to you, it's explained at the beginning of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/run-background-service/create-service.html).

> The IntentService class provides a straightforward structure for running an operation on a single background thread. This allows it to handle long-running operations without affecting your user interface's responsiveness. Also, an IntentService isn't affected by most user interface lifecycle events, so it continues to run in circumstances that would shut down an AsyncTask

Comment: I have tried with IntentService also, But still same response

Comment: And you are using the own IntentService thread? not creating another one?

Comment: IntentService used without thread because it having own Runnable . But using Service i used new Thread.